# First installation of Arch Linux after Dban wipe on an HP Mini

Tags: linux, arch-linux, partition

installing arch linux on old hp mini laptop.

I first wiped the hard drive using dban.

Did a Usb install.

I've created a partition table, after following several installation guides on youtube and other places.

I think the next step after creating partitions is to format them? or at least format the root partition.

keep getting this error
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

David

Comment: Have you unplugged the Arch Live USB? Coz you are not supposed to do that (unless you booted with parameter `copytoram`).

Comment: this may have been the problem, thankyou..mkfs.ext4 seems to have worked for sda1, Do I do the same for the other two partitions?

Answer (score 1):

Your disklabel is `DOS` which probably means that you are trying to install arch with `UEFI boot`.

If you want to use `fdisk` you must use a MBR(this is used with BIOS).

If you still want to use UEFI you need to make your partition with `gdisk`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.I am using MBR with a Bios not a UEFI.  I am under the impression that I have no choice if I have a BIOS system I need to use MBR.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the problem (which seems more like a problem with the USB drive), and most tools work with GPT anyway.